How would you read this time change with the given note equivalence?
Without the note equivalence I would just read the following as "play twice as fast". In this case though it seems like nothing changes from 3/4 to 3/8, since the beats are made to be equal. Is this correct?
(The time change is from 3/4 to 3/8)


Yeah that’s a bit odd. What’s this from?

Keep in mind that the given equivalence may be erroneous: it could be from an editor rather than the composer; it could be from a composer who thought it meant something other than what it actually means; or it could be from a transcriber who misread a smudge in the source as a dot.  If you can find another source or another edition, do.

For context, it comes from a music reading exercise from a course im taking

Ah, in a music-reading exercise, it's just sort of a trick question, I think. :)

Correct, nothing changes.
Since the beat doesn't change (rather, the measure length doesn't change), the tempo stays the same. Let's say the 3/4 section is 100 bpm, which translates to 100 quarter notes per minute. When arriving in 3/8, it stays 100 bpm, which means 100 eighth notes per minute.
Put another way, in 3/4 100 bpm (1.666... quarter-note beats/second), a measure lasts 5 seconds. In 3/8 100bpm (1.666... eighth-note beats/second), a measure also lasts 5 seconds.

Since the legend states dotted minim = dotted crotchet, and the notes themselves are half the previous value, status quo is established. No need to change anything. Which is rather a strange state of affairs. The time signature could have stayed the same, and the 'new' note values doubled what is shown - where's the difference? A somewhat pointless change, in my opinion.

Yes, I should add that it comes from a reading exercise and not an actual music sheet

The metric equation is saying that the duration of the note values change.
In this case, dotted minim = dotted crotchet says that the duration of a measure in the old time signature will sound for the same duration as a measure in the new time signature.  (Or equivalently, a crotchet in the old is going to sound like a quaver in the new.)
Another way to represent this would be with an absolute tempo change, e.g. if the tempo was initially crotchet = 120 [BMP], then at the time signature change the tempo would become quaver = 120 (i.e. the tempo stays the same but the note values halve).

Alternatively, this could also be represented with just one time signature throughout (see below), but the change can make it easier to read.  The following two lines should also sound the same as the two above:


If this time signature change occurred without a metric equation (or if the metric equation was quaver = quaver) then a quaver on either side should sound the same. But this would mean that the duration of a measure would change (it would halve).
